# Why blank items in flattened list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, recursion, flatten

I am trying following recursive function to flatten sent list which may contain sublist items:

```
def myflatten(slist, outlist=[]):
    for sl in slist:
        if type(sl) == list:    
            outlist.append(myflatten(sl, outlist))
        else: 
            outlist.append(sl)
    return outlist

print("myflatten list=", myflatten([1,[5,6,7],3,4,[7,8,9]]))
```

Output:

```
myflatten list= [1, 5, 6, 7, [...], 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, [...]]
```

Why am I getting `[...]` for every sublist and how can I avoid getting this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: `[...]` indicates the list contains itself

Comment: I think the problem is that you're updating the `default` reference for `outlist`. For instance, if you call `myflatten([1])`, and then call `myflatten([2])`, you'll get `[1, 2]`

Comment: This isn't the cause of your problem, but watch out for the [Default mutable gotcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) in your function definition there. Even if you get your code working, it might produce surprising results if you call it more than once.

Comment: @turbulencetoo Interesting! Hadn't seen that before, learn something new everyday!

Comment: @Kevin Actually, I think *it is* the cause of the problem. This is a recursive call.

Comment: @MatiasCicero, The problem would still occur even if he deleted the default argument and instead required an explicit reference. [Example](https://ideone.com/qstXH9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existing answers provide good explanations to why the [...] self-reference occurs, but their suggested revisions to the code don't do anything to address the [default mutable argument gotcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) that's waiting to bite you.

Here's a solution that doesn't require an `outlist` argument:

```
def myflatten(slist):
    outlist = []
    for sl in slist:
        if isinstance(sl, list):    
            outlist.extend(myflatten(sl))
        else: 
            outlist.append(sl)
    return outlist

print("myflatten list=", myflatten([1,[5,6,7],3,4,[7,8,9]]))
```

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly. `extend` is a useful function.

Comment: Keeping a blank `accumulator` as an argument is common in Scheme/Racket/Lisp-derived languages (as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29425944/racket-accumulator-list-function )

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that myflatten is returning a list. So when you append the results of myflatten to the outlist it is appending a list. Try setting outlist equal to the result of myflatten:

```
def myflatten(slist, outlist=[]):
    for sl in slist:
        if type(sl) == list:    
            outlist = myflatten(sl, outlist) #HERE IS THE CHANGE
        else: 
            outlist.append(sl)
    return outlist

print("myflatten list=", myflatten([1,[5,6,7],3,4,[7,8,9]]))
```

Comment: But with this I find subsequent calls keep adding to outlist created by previous call to the function. How to correct that?

Comment: @rnso can you give me an example oh what you mean?

Comment: Try `print(myflatten([1])); print(myflatten([2]))` on your function. You will get `[1,2]` as output of second command.

Comment: Interesting, learned something new. Kevin's answer works better since it doesn't use the outlist as a parameter. I could update this one but since his answer works, I won't unless you would like me to.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: Yep, that's what I had seen in Kevin's link, which means that using outlist as a parameter is a bad idea. There are some other answers that work better for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

You've created an infinite list. The `[...]` entries in the list point back to the list itself. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160162/what-is-the-ellipsis-in-a-python-list) for more details.

This is because when you make a recursive call, you pass in the `outlist` object itself, then return it and append it to itself. A subtle problem! But an easy fix; you'll want to use `=` for the recursive call, not `append`. Or perhaps `extend`, and pass in an empty list.

```
def myflatten(slist):
    outlist = []
    for sl in slist:
        if type(sl) == list:    
            outlist.extend(myflatten(sl))
        else: 
            outlist.append(sl)
    return outlist
```

You can even get rid of a parameter, which is nice.

Answer (score 1):

Another option that doesn't use `list.extend`. I'd rearrange your code a bit, and try to avoid default parameters:

```
def myflatten(slist):
    flat = []
    if isinstance(slist, list):
        for item in slist:
            flat += myflatten(item)
    else:
        flat.append(slist)
    return flat
```

Comment: @rnso Indeed. I don't know if there is any difference in efficiency, but it shouldn't be too big anyway.